# Is it possible to extend a Kubernetes CRD with a "sub-class" CRD?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

As an example, if I define a CRD of `kind: Animal`, can I define a CRD, `Dog`, as a specific `type` of `Animal`? The `Dog` CRD would have a different/extended schema requirement than the base `Animal` CRD.

My goal here is to be able to do a `kubectl get animals` and be able to see all the different `type`'s of `Animals` that were created.

This seems to have been achieved by using the `type` metadata for certain resources like `Secret`, but I can't seem to find how to achieve this with a CRD.

**Note**: my real use case isn't around storing `Animals`, but, it's just a typical example from OOP.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a feature of Kubernetes. All Secret objects are of the same Kind, and Type is just a string field.